# what is the difference between .capitalize and .capitalize!(or .map & .map!...etc.) and in ruby

Tags: ruby

learning how to code with Ruby and was trying learn from test first.
and I stumbled something funny.

I was trying to capitalize every word but

```html
title = 'stuart little'
a = title.split

a.each do |x|
x.capitalize
end

a.join(' ')
```

This one's result is 'stuart little'

but if I add the ! in capitalize

```html
title = 'stuart little'
a = title.split

a.each do |x|
x.capitalize!
end

a.join(' ')
```

it ends up with the result I want which is 'Stuart Little'

just .capitalize should work shouldn't it? since I'm just capitalizing the words. and what makes .capitalize! work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a method has a `!` at the end in Ruby, it is commonly referred to as a bang-method.  The exclamation point indicates that the method is the dangerous version of another method.

In this case, `capitalize!` will modify your string, while `capitalize` will return a new string object. Since you are later calling on your original objects (the strings in `a`), your code will only work with `capitalize!`.  To make the code work with `capitalize`, you would have to set that index of the array to the result of the method, e.g. `a[index] = x.capitalize`

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to learn I like to go to the source 
for [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) for [map!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map). the source would tell you what the difference is

> map- Invokes the given block once for each element of self.

and

> map! - Invokes the given block once for each element of self,
>   replacing the element with the value returned by the block.